# Button instance text

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

How can I change the text of a button instance without affect the other button text?
I belive an AS aproach would solve it but I don't know how to do it.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Depands how your button is configured. There is probably a textfield inside there, you need to get a reference.

Exemple

```
myButton:Button = Button( visual.getChildByName("myBtn") );
myText:TextField = TextField( myButton.getChildByName("myTextfield");

myText.Text = "blablabla";
```

For this you need to have a button with the instance name `"myBtn"` and inside of it you need a textfield named `"myTextField"`.

Good luck :)

Comment: You should mark my answer as the correct one. click the check icon under the upvote / downvote

Comment: Access of undefined property myText.
Illegal assignment to class TextField.
Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.text:TextField to an unrelated type Class.
Access of undefined property myButton.
Access of undefined property visual.
Call to a possibly undefined method Button.
Access of undefined property Button.